# canvas image size in html5

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasPnl");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var locationtxt = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = document.getElementById("tempImg").src;
imageObj.onload = function () {
    var x = 188;
    var y = 30;
    var width = 200;
    var height = 137;
    context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height);
    context.font = "20pt Calibri";
    context.fillText(locationtxt, 40, 40);
};
```

```
<canvas id="canvasPnl" width="132" height="120" style="border:0px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

The size of the image is becoming bigger and it is not fitting in canvas and also the image is rotated.

How to get original image in canvas?

Comment: you have provided width and height of image (200, 137) greater than width and height of canvas (132, 120) and also you have given the starting point to draw the image as (x=188, y=30) which is lying outside the canvas

Comment: Try to change the height and width in imageObj.onload function. because it is specifying the image height width which are greater thn the canvas size u have specified. on either cases, make them equal, the canvas height width and the image height width.. let me know what happens...

Comment: i fixed the changes like u said that is i did height and width same to both canvas and image still the result is same :(

Comment: give (x=0, y=0) as I said your drawing point is lying outside the canvas

Comment: no still the same :( x=0 y=0 is also not working

Answer (score 3):

Ok, take a look at your reworked code below.

Notice "imageObj.src = document.getElementById("tempImg").src;" must go **after** imageObj.onload.

I have no access to your locationtxt or your tempImg, so I assume you are sure they are not the source of your problem.

This line of code will take an image of ANY size and force it to fit in your specified canvas size by scaling it.  When it scales, you may get image distortion if your canvas size is not proportional to your image size.

```
context.drawImage(imageObj,0,0,imageObj.width,imageObj.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Here is your code -- just modified a bit :)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasPnl");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var locationtxt = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(imageObj,0,0,imageObj.width,imageObj.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    context.font = "20pt Calibri";
    context.fillText(locationtxt, 40, 40);
};
imageObj.src = document.getElementById("tempImg").src;
```

Comment: no now it is displaying 2 images one with text and one with image

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
#mycanvas
{
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var img = new Image, ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
  var img1=new Image;
  img.src = 'ship.png';
  img1.src='3D025.jpg';
  img.addEventListener('load', function () {
     var width = img.naturalWidth; // this will be 300
  var height = img.naturalHeight; // this will be 400

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      var x = 260, y = 0;

      return function () {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, y);
        ctx.drawImage(img, x, 300,width,height);

        x += 1;
        if (x > ctx.canvas.width) {
          x = 260;
         width=width-10;
         height=height-10;
         ctx.drawImage(img, x, 300,width,height);
        }
        if (x == 750) {
          x = 260;

        }
      };
    }(), 1000/40);
  }, false);
}, false);

</script>

<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" height="600" width="1000"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```